# Why do ARM saves return address in Link Register instead of the stack?

Tags: arm, processor

I have been searching for this answer for over a week now with no luck. I have so far learnt that stack saves the return address when function nesting or interrupt occurs, but recently I learned that the modern processors use the Link Register to achieve the same goal. After some research, I came to know that the stack was indeed being used to save the return address in older processors. However, It doesn't make sense to me why the modern processors use an entire separate register ( LR ) to save the return address when the older implementation was working?  What are the benefits of LR over stack-based implementation?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It’s a register, not memory. It’s much faster to use.

Comment: speed for one, memory is really really slow.  More registers in general are faster than using fewer registers and more stack.  Same answer for passed in parameters, you will see registers used vs stack as a preference if the architecture has enough registers.

Comment: not limited to arm.

Comment: That makes sense, registers are faster to access. However, since we have 1 LR if the function goes more than 1 level deep nesting, it forces us to store LR to the stack which will, in turn, reduce the speed of the processor. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 4):

RISC architectures tend to have fewer special instructions or behaviours - and instead standard instructions are used for stack management. This usually means that programs are larger, the CPU itself, simpler, and the compiler is expected to optimise harder

Consider:

```
int bar(int a)
{
    return a * a;
}

void foo()
{
    bar(22);
}


foo();
```

Here, `bar()` is a *leaf function* - one that doesn't go on to make further function calls.  Therefore, the return address in `LR` will never be overwritten. As a consequence, there's no need for it to be written to the stack at all.  This saves and load and a store from/to memory.

`foo()` on the other hand will mutate `LR` because it makes a function call, so it will need to store the caller's return address on the stack.

Contrast this to an architecture in which making a function call automatically pushes the return address to the stack - this optimisation is not possible.

All version the ARM Procedure Call Standard define a *callee saves* registers for function call - registers that the caller can expect to be maintained over a function call.  If the function is trivial, it again results in no memory access.

In interrupts, timing is often more critical.  ARM CPUs have a set of shadow registers which are only accessible in interrupt state.  This means that trivial interrupt handlers can be written that require no memory access.

Comment: So, do you mean to say if the function nesting is only one level down it is an optimization since we are accessing the return address from the register, instead of the memory? But for deeper function calls it will be same since it involves storing  LR to stack. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Correct - however, leaf functions are by definition small, and called frequently.  Because of their size, the loads/stores to memory would constitute a large proportion of their execution time.

Comment: You might like to look at the SPARC architecture - which has a much larger register file and a sliding window onto it that moves on function call, potentially eliminating a lot of spill to the stack.  After a certain number of function calls, there's a huge spill to the stack.

Comment: Thanks, Marko, It makes sense now.